# How to find volume generated by rotating the region using Shell method

Tags: calculus, volume

Refer to the figure below to determine the volume generated by rotating the given region around
of the specified axis:

[image]

a) **$R_2$ around AB**

Using the formula $A(x)=2\pi(radius)(height)$

Why my radius will be $(1-x)$ and my height will be
$(1-\sqrt{x})$?

**Aplying in the Volume Formula:**
$$=\int_{0}^{1}2\pi(1-x)(1-\sqrt{x})=\frac{7\pi}{15}$$
So my volume will be $\frac{7\pi}{15}$

I didn't understand the reason for the radius and height values.

**b) $R_1$ around $OA$**

**c) $R_2$ around $OA$**

**d) $R_3$ around $OA$**

**e) $R_3$ around $AB$**

**f) $R_1$ around $BC$**

Can someone explain to me how I determine the radius and height to be able to develop the letters b through e?

Comment: I don't understand what you propose, could you sketch please?? @Yooo

Answer (score 1):

The radius is the distance from the solid to the axis of rotation.  For part a), the axis is at $x = 1$, so the distance is $1-x$, for $x$ between $0$ and the boundary of the solid.

If you are not sure, you can do a sanity check:  The closest region $R_1$ gets to the axis is a distance of $0$ when $x = 1$.  Note that this agrees with the answer because $1-1 = 0$.

Let's do part (c).  The axis of rotation is $y = 0$.  Because our shells will now be oriented along the $y-$axis, we solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.  That is, $x = y^2$, where $0 \leq y \leq 1$.  The distance between $R_2$ the the axis $OA$ is $y$.  The height of the shells will be $y^2$.  So, this gives us
$$2\pi \int_{y=0}^{1}y(y^2) dy.$$

Comment: and why my height will be $(1-\sqrt{x})$?

Comment: Because the top of region $R_2$ is $1$ and the lowest part of the region is along the curve $y = \sqrt{x}$.  The height is then the distance between the top and bottom which is $1-\sqrt{x}$.